# How to use filelight KDE GUI app remotely by fish/ssh protocols in 2023?

Tags: ssh, kde, disk-usage, fish-protocol

Back in the dayZ, we can run [filelight](https://apps.kde.org/filelight/) from within a console by typing:

```
filelight fish://root@remote//home
```

but it seems it now doesn't work anymore. Any workaround ? Is the *scheme* is wrong ? Tried `ssh://`, no cigar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround:

```
sshfs root@remote:/home ./mount_dir
filelight ./mount_dir
```

Is there another transparent way, please tell me